# How to invoke onPrepareOptionsMenu() from BroadcastReceiver in Android?

Tags: java, android

> I am beginner to android,I have included 2 icons in internet.xml
>   ,based on the network connection(Example if network is connected it
>   should show connected icon or else it should show not connected icon
>   on the toolbar),for that I have created onPrepareOptionsMenu() in
>   activity as well as BroadcastReceiver to broadcast the present network
>   status based on that the icon has to change dynamically.
>
> Here I have used Intent to broadcast the current network status,it is
>   again relaunching the activity,I don't know how to call
>   onPrepareOptionsMenu() inside the BroadcastReceiver class to
>   automatically update menu items in toolbar based on the network
>   status.
>
> Can anyone help me to do this?.

```
**ConnectionActivity**

public class ConnectionActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        Menu menu;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_parser);
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.internet, menu);
            return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            boolean online = false;
            MenuItem netMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.network_signal);
            MenuItem nonetMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.network_signal_off);
            int status = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatus(this);
            if (status == 1 || status == 2)
                online = true;
            else
                online = false;
            netMenuItem.setVisible(online);
            nonetMenuItem.setVisible(!online);

            return true;
        }

    }

**NetworkUtil.java**


            public class NetworkUtil {
            public static int TYPE_WIFI = 1;
            public static int TYPE_MOBILE = 2;
            public static int TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED = 0;


            public static int getConnectivityStatus(Context context) {
                ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

                NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                if (null != activeNetwork) {
                    if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                        Log.d("WIFI CONNECTED", activeNetwork.getType() + "");
                        return TYPE_WIFI;
                    }
                    if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
                        Log.d("MOBILE CONNECTED", activeNetwork.getType() + "");
                        return TYPE_MOBILE;
                    }
                }
                Log.d("NOT CONNECTED", TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED + "");
                return TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED;
            }

            public static String getConnectivityStatusString(Context context) {
                int conn = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatus(context);
                String status = null;
                if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_WIFI) {
                    status = "Wifi enabled";
                } else if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_MOBILE) {
                    status = "Mobile data enabled";
                } else if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED) {
                    status = "Not connected to Internet";
                }
                return status;
            }
        }

**NetworkChangeReceiver**


            public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String status = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatusString(context);
                Toast.makeText(context, status, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               Intent activityIntent = new Intent(context, ParserActivity.class);
                activityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(activityIntent);
            }
        }

 **Menifest.xml**

     <receiver
            android:name=".NetworkChangeReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

**internet.xml**


         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
            <item
                android:title="signal_off"
                android:id="@+id/network_signal_off"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_signal_wifi_off_black_24dp"
                app:showAsAction="always"></item>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/network_signal"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_signal_wifi_4_bar_black_24dp"
                android:title="Signal"
                app:showAsAction="always"></item>
        </menu>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is another way of doing so, not by calling `onPrepareOptionsMenu`

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                try {
                    if (isOnline(context)) {
                        // show online icon
                        ConnectionActivity.setMenuVisible(true);
                    } else {
                       // show offline icon
                        ConnectionActivity.setMenuVisible(false);

                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            private boolean isOnline(Context context) {
                try {
                    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                    //should check null because in airplane mode it will be null
                    return (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
```

=============================================================================

```
public class ConnectionActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        Menu menu;
        private BroadcastReceiver mNetworkReceiver;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_parser);
            mNetworkReceiver = new NetworkChangeReceiver();
            registerReceiver(mNetworkReceiver, new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
        }

        @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.internet, menu);
    this.menu = menu;
    this.menu.findItem(R.id.network_signal).setVisible(false);
    this.menu.findItem(R.id.network_signal_off).setVisible(false);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

        public static void setMenuVisible(boolean isOnline) {
            if (isOnline) {
                if (menu != null) {
                    menu.findItem(R.id.network_signal).setVisible(true);
                    menu.findItem(R.id.network_signal_off).setVisible(false);
                }
            } else {
                if (menu != null) {
                    menu.findItem(R.id.network_signal_off).setVisible(true);
                    menu.findItem(R.id.network_signal).setVisible(false);
                }
            }
        }

        private void unregisterNetworkChanges() {
            try {
                unregisterReceiver(mNetworkReceiver);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            unregisterNetworkChanges();
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you..its working fine,but while launching the app it showing both icons at the same time in the toolbar

Comment: check my edited answer, you can make both of menu icons visibility gone and make them visible according to your need.

Comment: if it's working fine then do accept and upvote my answer.

Comment: got it @Lucky..but one icon should be present based on the network status,I have fixed that issue. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

if you call `invalidateOptionsMenu();` which will trigger the

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

so in here you make the change

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //your logic 
        //invalidate the options menu
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }
```

Comment: while trying inValidateOptionsMenu((Activity)context) in broadcast receiver class getting ClassCastException @vikas kumar

Comment: if you are not calling in the same activity this will not work. otherwise you can set some flag to check if int.ernet is working then on the intended activity check that activity and draw menus accordingly

Comment: could you explain with some sample code snippet,because I am new to android if you tell with some example it would be very helpful @vikas